# Testcafe - Populate input field based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm not an expert in Javascript by any means and just getting my head round testcafe which I'm really enjoying.

However as a simple test I'm trying to populate a input field based on what was selected from a dropdown. Really simple, it's a Title field, so Mr, Mrs, etc.. Based on if 'Mr' was selected then populate with male name. If 'Mrs' then populate will female name.

However I'm unable to read the value chosen once it has been selected to pass into my If...else statement and it always goes to the default last option. Can somebody help me?

My code:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

const TitleSelect = Selector('#title');
const TitleOption = TitleSelect.find('option');
const FirstName = Selector('#firstname');

fixture `Getting Started`
.page //any page with a Title dropdown and Firstname input field;

test('My first test', async t => {
await t
    .click(TitleSelect)
    .click(TitleOption.withText('Mrs'))

    if (TitleOption === 'Mr') {
        await t
        .wait(1000)
        .typeText(FirstName, "Wayne")

    } else if (TitleOption === 'Mrs') {
        await t
        .wait(1000)
        .typeText(FirstName, "Waynetta")

    } else {
        await t
        .typeText(FirstName, "something else");
    } 

    await t
    .takeScreenshot({
        path: 'If_else_statment.jpg',
        fullPage: true
      })
    .wait(2000)   
    ;        
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the input's state:

```
const value = await TitleSelect.value;
```

For more information, please refer to
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#obtain-element-state

Comment: Thank you very much, I'd been looking at the documentation for ages however had the const sitting outside of my tests. Now moved within and this now works as intended,  thanks again